# Calculating the number of rows in a column

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to import the data in the list of listbox1 in the word from column "A" in the excel

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim excelobject As Object, wb As Object, r As Long, i As Integer
Dim hh As Boolean
Dim a As String
Dim b As Integer
Set excelobject = CreateObject("excel.application") 
excelobject.Visible = False   

Set wb = excelobject.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

Me.ListBox1.Visible = True

Me.ListBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(UCase(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value), UCase(a)) > 0 Then
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next i
excelobject.Quit
end sub
```

but run `wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` msgbox display "object required". Where did I write wrong, why in Excel, this property is available？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the constant `xlUp` in `wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Because you are not importing or referencing `Excel` library into your project, there is no way for your program to know what you mean by `xlUp`.

Luckily, you can obtain the value inside that constant by going to any Visual Basic Immediate tab in Excel VBA and simply typing

```
? xlUp
```

Output:

> -4162

Try replacing your line:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

with this one:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(-4162).Row
' or if you worry that constant can have different values in 
' different Excel versions, you may simply explicitly define it as wb.xlDirection.xlUp

wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(wb.xlDirection.xlUp).Row
```

Note: the same issue can also apply for the `Rows.count`. In that case, you need to explicitly define it as `wb.Sheets(1).Rows.count` instead:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(wb.Sheets(1).Rows.count, 1).End(wb.xlDirection.xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Succeeded, Thank you so much

Comment: Nice catch. I wasn't even thinking that this was not in the Excel's VBE. +1 Well done.

Comment: You can also add `Const xlUp As Long = -4162` in module's declaration.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs better yet, is to just call it `wb.xlUp` and never worry about its value. See my updated answer

Comment: @kerrry if this answer fixed the problem, it means you're not specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. Go to tools/options, and tick the checkbox for "require variable declaration". The VBE will refuse to compile & run code that contains undeclared variables. Systematically declaring all variables as a mere habit, and consistently specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, will forever prevent this error, and many others in the future.

Comment: @ Mat's Mug, Thanks, I will do it

Answer (score 2):

If I may make a suggestion, be sure to use **Early Binding** when accessing other libraries, such as Excel from Word.  Not all libraries work with early binding, but when used, you get all the benefits of intellisense, plus all enumerations (what `xlUp` is a part of) are visible.  Also the code should run just a bit faster.

You would have to tick the `Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library` under Tools -> References...

(It may be 13.0, 14.0, or 16.0, depending on your version of Office)

Your code would then look like

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim excelobject As Excel.Application, wb As Object, r As Long, i As Integer
    Dim hh As Boolean
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As Integer
    Set excelobject = New Excel.Application
    excelobject.Visible = False

    Set wb = excelobject.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

    Me.ListBox1.Visible = True

    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    For i = 2 To wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(UCase(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value), UCase(a)) > 0 Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    wb.Close
    excelobject.Quit
End Sub
```

I would also close the workbook before closing Excel.  It may need an argument like false to indicate not to save the sheet.

As @Mat's Mug correctly suggests, without using `Option Explicit`, uninitialised variables are `Variant` with an initial value of `0` by default.  Unhelpful for debugging.

Early Binding in conjunction with `Option Explicit` will do more error checking at compile time and help eliminate errors.

Answer (score 1):

So, my first concern is that you may not be opening the workbook correctly. Possibly an incorrect path or file name.

Also, just like you referenced `.Cells` to your workbook, you also need to reference `Rows.Count`. I added a `With...End With` statement for this reason.

#### Code:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim excelobject As Object, wb As Object, r As Long, i As Integer
    Dim a
    
    Set excelobject = CreateObject("excel.application")
    excelobject.Visible = False
    Set wb = excelobject.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "YOU DO NOT HAVE THE CORRECT PATH TO YOUR WORKBOOK"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With wb.Worksheets(1)
        a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox a
    excelobject.Quit
End Sub
```

You should also avoid using `sheets()` and instead use `Worksheets()`. While in many cases sheets() will work for you, if you have a chart or something other than a worksheet as index 1, then that could be causing your error.

Think about it this way:  *All worksheets are sheets, but not all sheets are worksheets.*

Comment: run  `a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ` mgsbox display "application-defined or object-defined error "

Comment: That may be because I used your `wb.sheets()` method. You should actually be using `Worksheets()`. I will edit in a moment.

Comment: also show "application-defined or object-defined error ", can you create a test.xlsx in your computer?  thank you very much